# Can I delete the default gateway on an interface, without knowing the interface's IP?

Tags: netsh

I'm trying to write a script that will involve modifying the IPv4 configuration of an interface. The interface may or may not already have any of the following configured:

- IP Address
- Subnet Mask
- Default Gateway
- DNS Servers
- WINS Servers

When my script is done, I want *only* the options that I have set to be configured. (e.g.: If I don't set a Gateway, DNS, or WINS server, then I want none to be configured.) I figure the easiest way to ensure this is to wipe out the existing configuration as much as I can and then build up just what I need.

Leaving the existing IP Address and Subnet Mask is okay, because these will definitely be overwritten every time. It looks fairly simple to delete DNS and WINS servers with `netsh`.

```
netsh interface ipv4 delete dns "LAN" all
netsh interface ipv4 delete wins "LAN" all
```

My problem comes with deleting the gateway. It seems that every `netsh` command that is used to modify the default gateway requires the current IP address as a parameter. However, this will not always be something that is known. Is there not a way to use `netsh` to just delete all the gateways configured for an interface, without specifying the IP?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Are you willing to set a new IP/mask?

Comment: Windows 7/2008. And part of the script's purpose is to set a new IP & Subnet in the first place. So, I think I just realized my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Delete default gateway:

```
route delete -p 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 4):

> Leaving the existing IP Address and Subnet Mask is okay, because these will definitely be overwritten every time.

Since you're overwriting the IP and Subnet Mask anyway, just use `netsh` to delete the gateway in the same step. e.g.:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0 none
```

Here, you place *none* where the Default Gateway would normally go. This specifies that no gateway will be used with this IP.

Comment: @lszi "Local Area Connection" - unknown interface?

Comment: @STTR Your interface may be named differently. Use `netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces` to find the correct name. Also make sure to replace `192.168.1.100` and `255.255.255.0` with the actual IP Address and Subnet Mask you want to use on that interface.

Comment: this is ok if you only have 1 NIC... of course you can repeat for every NIC... nevertheless not OK if you rely on DHCP... missing a better way I would endorse the solution presented next by STTR, relying in route command